# Убрать повторяющиеся слеши одним редиректом htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

пытаюсь сделать редирект например с ура site.ru/// на site.ru
Вставил в htaccess следующий код:

```html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*?)\/{2,}(.*?)$
RewriteRule . %1/%2 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} //
RewriteRule .* /$0 [R=301,L]
```

И все бы хорошо, но вот только он делает сначала редирект с site.ru/// на site.ru//, затем с site.ru// на site.ru/ и уже потом site.ru/ на site.ru

Как сделать это одним редиректом?

Answer (score 0):

Проблема заключается в том, что редирект выполняется постепенно, удаляя один слэш за раз. Чтобы выполнить редирект сразу, замените ваш код в .htaccess на следующий:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s[^?]*//
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/{2,}(.*)$ $1/$2 [R=301,L]
```

вот что делает этот код:

1. RewriteEngine On включает модуль mod_rewrite.
2. RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s[^?]*// проверяет, есть ли двойной слэш или более в запрошенном URL.
3. RewriteRule ^(.+?)/{2,}(.*)$ $1/$2 [R=301,L] ищет двойной слэш или более в запрашиваемом пути и заменяет их одним слэшем, выполняя редирект с кодом 301 (Moved Permanently).

Comment: Спасибо за ваш ответ, но теперь появляется сразу статус 200 совсем без редиректа, то есть слеши остаются
Прикрепляю фрагмент кода, вроде все делаю правильно:

Comment: <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s[^?]*//
  RewriteRule ^(.+?)/{2,}(.*)$ $1/$2 [R=301,L]

  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
  # Если NetCat стоит в подпапке, например mysite, то
  # RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /mysite/netcat/require/e404.php
  # в противном случае
  RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /netcat/require/e404.php
  RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE:%{HTTP:If-Modified-Since}]
  RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_IF_NONE_MATCH:%{HTTP:If-None-Match}]